# JPA Inserting an entity if not exists in concurrent operation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple use case:

I want to insert an entity that doesn't exist.

Here is the entity class, it has combined unique columns:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                "firstName", "lastName"
        })
})
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
```

And here is the simple insertion logic:

```
 Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepository.findByFirstNameAndLastName("John", "Doe");
        if (!customer.isPresent()) {
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("John", "Doe"));
        }
```

when I call this via concurrent threads, I get this `ConstraintViolationException` and that's obvious

```
 insert into customer (first_name, last_name, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-200]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.UKKIYY7M3FWM4VO5NIL9IBP5846_INDEX_5 ON PUBLIC.CUSTOMER(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES 8"; SQL statement:
 insert into customer (first_name, last_name, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:459) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
```

I can catch this exception, but ConstraintViolationException can occur in any scenario other than the unique index.

I also tried JPA's **Optimistic locking** but it seems to work only in the update and delete operations but not in insertion.

I don't want native query (like `ON DUPLICATE KEY` in mysql, `ON CONFLICT` in PostgresSQL) because I want to make operations to be handled in JPA itself.

Also, I cannot make it threadsafe because the application will be running on multiple JVMs.

Is there any way somehow I can handle this, like locking on insert or atleast update on same keys?

Comment: I think it's normal for multiple processes/threads to execute insert statements at the same time, only one will succeed, the others just need to catch the exception, and there are no other bad consequences.If you have multiple processes/threads executing update statements simultaneously, you may need to do some synchronization ( Optimistic locking / Pessimistic locking ).   In addition, you can use distributed locks (apache curator, redisson..) to make it threadsafe cross JVM.